# search for adobe illustrator files that contain specific content

Tags: file, search, adobe-illustrator, advanced-search

i am trying to find an .ai file on my laptop 
i know some elements of the file like a vector logo i have use in it
a .jpg image in the artwork
and some of the text written within a text box in the artwork.

the file is probably around three months old.

i am sure that it is in .ai (or maybe .pdf)..

i have used search by date in windows and by file type but the amount of files i have from around that time is hundreds.

i am looking for a way to search for a file based on some elements / objects within the file. primarily an illustrator file or pdf Cheers? i am using windows 7 and illustrator cc

Answer (score 0):

I don't think windows explorer would have that kind of option. Maybe you can think of keywords that would possibly match your .ai file name that you can use to search the file.